# how to disable ActionLink in razor after 2 minutes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor

First time using StackOverflow.
I have a table with different data and I want to disable actionlink after two minutes

```
<table class="table">
    <tr class="btn-danger">
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model._art.libelle)
        </th>
        <th>
            Image
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model._art.prix_initial)
        </th>
        <th>
            Prix Courant
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr class="btn-primary">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item._art.libelle)
        </td>
        <td>
           <img  src="@Url.Content(item._art.img)" width="300" height="300"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item._art.prix_initial)
        </td>
        <td>
            @{ var prix_calcule = item.valeur_courante
                    * 0.1 * item._art.prix_initial
                     + item._art.prix_initial;
            }
            @prix_calcule
        </td>


        <td id="test">
            <h1>@Html.ActionLink("Encherir", "Encherir", new { id_article = item._art.id }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })</h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
  } 

</table>
```

I want after two minutes the actionLink "encherir" to be disabled.
I've tried javascript but unfortunately, it will disable just the first row in the table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Once you've delivered something to the browser, your control is very limited.  There are ways to hide it with Javascript, but users can just turn javascript off, which would leave it up forever.

The best way to handle this, though, is still to hide it with Javascript, but then also include an expiration token in the link.  Give it a unique, encrypted value as a GET argument that tells you when it expires.  Then, if the user clicks on the link they shouldn't have after two minutes, you can decode that token and return a "Sorry, your link expired" page instead of the real one.